# Ovid: "nimis ex vero nunc tibi nomen erit"

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check, poetry, ovidius, latin-to-english-translation

In [Ovid *Amores* 3.9, the elegy for Tibullus](http://www.sacred-texts.com/cla/ovid/lboo/lboo51.htm), we read:

> flebilis indignos, Elegeiia, solve capillos!
>   a! nimis ex vero nunc tibi nomen erit

My literal translation: "Tearful, loosen your undeserving hair, Elegy! Ah! Now you will have too true a name."

But what does the second line mean? Why will Elegy's name be "too true" after Tibullus's death?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elegeia was said to come from ἔλεγος, meaning "lament".

Ovid's pun is that now she will cry so much that she will really be Lament.